# Order by column in pageblock table

Tags: soql, pageblocktable

I have a pageblock table with 2 columns.

```
Public list<sobject> newlist{get;set;}
    List<sobject> testlist = [select id, column1,column2 from sobject order by column1];
for(sobject obj:testList){
newlist.add(obj);
}
```

VF PAGE:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!newlist}" var="var" styleClass="table table-hover color" >
        //Below updated as part of US139009 to change font style to bold
        <apex:column style="font-weight:800" value="{!var.column1}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!var.column2}"/>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I have data in object as like this,

```
test1 - 1
test1 - 2
test1 - 3
test2 - 4
test2 - 5
test3 - 6
```

Used order by to look it as follows,

```
test1 - 1
      - 2
      - 3

test2 - 4
      - 5

test3 - 6
```

This works fine.

But when i go and change the test 1 associated with 2 to test 12, the format is like this

```
test1 - 1

test 12 - 2

test1 - 3
test2 - 4
      - 5

test3 - 6
```

I want this in a way, that the test12 doesnt break the test 1 elements. All the elemts of column1 should be diplayed together.

How can i do this?

Comment: Please post your markup and code. It is difficult for us to infer what you mean by *changing test 1 to test 12*.

Comment: There is no input mechanism to modify any fields in what you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use a different sort than SOQL uses you will have to implement your own code. One approach is to make use of the [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm):

```
public class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    public SObject sob;
    public Wrapper(SObject sob) {
        this.sob = sob;
    }
    // Change this to order the items as you like
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        Wrapper that = (Wrapper) o;
        if (this.column1 < that.column1) return -1;
        else if (this.column1 > that.column1) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

that can then be used like this:

```
Wrapper[] wrappers = new Wrapper[] {};
for (SObject sob : [select id, column1,column2 from sobject]) {
    wrappers.add(new Wrapper(sob));
}
// This applies a sorting algorithm that compares list items via the compareTo method
wrapper.sort();
for (Wrapper w : wrappers) {
    newlist.add(w.sob);
}
```

If this seems like more work boiler plate code than it should be then I would agree with you. Apex is missing a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) mechanism that allows the sort algorithm to be defined independently of the objects being sorted.